# Is it safe to use 'Function' as a model name in Ruby and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it safe to use 'Function' as a model name in Ruby and Rails?

```
class Function < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

I expect some conflicts with some defaults classes, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Even if there are no conflicts in the latest versions of Ruby and Rails, I would tend to avoid such generic names because there are more descriptive names you could use for what the model represents. *Function* is pretty generic. It's not a good class name choice, in my opinion. Is it a *mathematical* function? Is it a *bodily* function? The name could reflect the type. And I wouldn't rule out it being used in a future update or Rails perchance...

Comment: valid remark, but if you put it inside a module, you should be safe.

Comment: It's not in a module, though.  He apparently wants to name an ActiveRecord model "Function".  Bad choice for many many reasons, most of which are pointed out in the various answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not in the reserved method and class names its generally ok to use

see list here
http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words

but using `function` might be confusing when reading the code or talking about it..

"See the function in Function class and make sure it functions properly"

Answer (score 1):

You can never be sure about potential name conflict. It may be fine at some point, but later, some library that you depend on may decide to use that name. A practical strategy people take is to put everything in a namespace (module) with a name you believe to be safe at that point. If that later conflicts with something, you can simply rename that namespace everywhere in your code without touching anything else.

Comment: I'd also be concerned about the name being completely unhelpful. It's a *what* function?

Answer (score 0):

```
    c700595-3:VtM deh0002a$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.1.5 :001 > Function
NameError: uninitialized constant Function
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vtm/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vtm/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vtm/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vtm/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/deh0002a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@vtm/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.1.5 :002 >
```

So you will be safe to declare a class like that.

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions Rails. Checking for only IRB is not enough.

Comment: updated answer, even in rails calling your class **Function** is fine.